# What is an "Nonexistent Asset" and how do I take care of it in Azure Media Services?

Tags: azure, assets, azure-media-services

I have several AMS (Azure Media Service) Jobs that finished, but have nothing to do with the original video asset. Those assets are called "**Nonexistent Asset**".

Why are such assets beeing created? How do I take care about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you seeing it display "Nonexistent Asset"? Are you seeing that in the API, Portal, or Media Services Explorer tool?

For this issue, please file a support request on azure.com so that we can get your account details and take a look.

Comment: I see it in the API. It is the name of the asset (IAsset.Name). Do you have a link? It seems I need to pay for filing a support request.

Comment: Send me your subscription ID,  Media Services account name, and the Region/Datacenter where your account is located. 
I'll open a support ticket to take a look at this quickly.

johndeu@microsoft.com